# Location Listener is not working on Network provider

Tags: android, gps

I have the following code, to experiment with locations from wifi:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
   Context mContext;
   TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContext=getApplicationContext();
    text=findViewById(R.id.text1);
    askpermissions();
    doLocationStuff();
}
void doLocationStuff(){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            text.append(location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLatitude());
            Toast.makeText(mContext, location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };


    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        text.setText("wifi gps");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }
}

void askpermissions(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
                    ,10);
        }
    }

}
```

when i set the provider as GPS_PROVIDER, the app works as it is supposed to (location appears in a textview and a toast).

However, when I use NETWORK_PROVIDER, nothing happens (textview stays at wifi gps and no toast appears). My app has permission for coarse and fine location and internet access, and both GPS and Wifi are enabled.

I assumed my router's location wasn't recorded, but when I open Google Maps, its estimate is much better with wifi on.

EDIT: The code works fine on a Samsung Galaxy A5 with android 5, but isnt working on a Huawei P8 lite with Android 6

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to check your permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I have added ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, and uses features android.hardware.location.network and android.hardware.location and nothing changed

Comment: You said that work fine in samsung, may this not about your code but som phone need user action for extra permission, try to set permission at your huawei in `Settings --> Apps ---> Advanced (left corner at bottom of the screen) ---> Ignore optimisation (last option of the menu) ---> Allowed ---> All Apps (it will now show all the apps on the list) ---> YOUR APPS ---> Allow` if this work you need extra permission too for some device.